# "read" Data with multiple IDs from OpenERP using java with apache xml-rpc

Tags: java, xml-rpc, xmlrpclib, odoo

Hi I am currently writing a servlet using [Apache XML-RPC](http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/index.html) connecting to OpenERP. There are not any good resources around, and the java examples are very minimalistic and far from complete on the OpenERP site.

Has anyone a clue where I could find an API on how and what I can call on the OpenERP side?

I would really appreciate that!!!

On a further note, I am specifically looking for the syntax on how to "read" data, using java, with an input of multiple ids.

```
XmlRpcClient client = new XmlRpcClient();
XmlRpcClientConfigImpl clientConfig = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();
clientConfig.setEnabledForExtensions(true);
clientConfig.setServerURL(new URL(urlStringObject));
client.setConfig(clientConfig);

Object[] params2 = { "city", "name", "email", "create_date","write_date" };

Vector<Object> arg = new Vector<Object>();

arg.add(database);
arg.add(1);
arg.add(password);
arg.add("res.partner.address");
arg.add("read");
arg.add(9); // <- THE PYTHON SYNTAX SAYS input 'LIST OF IDS' here What is the Jave equivalent???
arg.add(params2);

HashMap ids = (HashMap) client.execute("execute", arg);
```

**UPDATE**

```
/* Search for all ids */
                xmlrpcConfigLogin.setServerURL(new URL(urlStringObject));
                Object[] searchQuery = new Object[] {"id", "!=", -1 };

                Vector queryVector = new Vector();
                queryVector.addElement(searchQuery);

                Object[] params = new Object[] { database, theloginId , password, tableName, "search", queryVector };
                Object[] po_ids = (Object[]) xmlrpcLogin.execute("execute", params);                

                /* Send Read Query */
                Object[] readQuery = {"name"};      

                Vector<Object> arg = new Vector<Object>();      
                arg.add(database);
                arg.add(1);
                arg.add(password);
                arg.add(tableName);
                arg.add("read");
                arg.add(po_ids);
                arg.add(readQuery);         

                HashMap globalMap = new HashMap();

                Object[] hm = (Object[]) xmlrpcLogin.execute("execute", arg);                                   
                for (Object object : hm) {
                    HashMap hash = (HashMap)object;                             
                    globalMap.put("name", hash.get("name"));              
                    _log.info(hash.get("name"));
                }
```

As you can see: It takes an Object[] of ids as input (po_ids)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you've read through the [developer book description of XML-RPC](http://doc.openerp.com/v5.0/developer/6_22_XML-RPC_web_services/index.html). I think that it's just a wrapper around all the [methods in the ORM class](http://doc.openerp.com/v5.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/methods.html). That's all the documentation I've seen. Other than that, I run OpenERP in debug mode and put a break point in the `LocalService.__call__()` method to see what parameters the client is sending to the server. (It's in `server/bin/netsvc.py`.) I've also seen developers just log every request that comes through that method.

As for how to make the calls in Java, I'm not familiar with the `XmlRpcClient` API, but it looks like it will accept an array of objects for a list, and probably anything that is enumerable. See if the [description of data types](http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/types.html) is helpful, and check out the [word tracker tutorial](http://www.wordtracker.com/docs/api/ch03s02.html). It uses a `Vector` to hold a list parameter.

Comment: Hi Don thanks for the insights, I have solved the issue, but the other things you mention certainly help a lot. I have found a forum entry with lots of good java examples -> http://www.openerp.com/forum/topic15581.html

Comment: I always get an html in the response. Do you know y

Comment: I suggest you ask a separate question, @tejas, including the code you are using and the response you are getting.

Comment: I have asked a question here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20794411/connect-to-openerp-in-android. @DonKirkby, could you please look into that and help me? I am struggling from days

Comment: hello @mahatmanich , dou you have alternative forum's post link you sent above? I need to peek a little about it, for OpenErp 6.1. It seems Odoo didn't migrate old forum post. Thank you.