# Cannot Login to OpenERP in android

Tags: java, android, magento, odoo, xml-rpc

With reference to the question here,

[Android OpenErp Search Request XMLRPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648724/android-openerp-search-request-xmlrpc)

I am trying to establish a search and login request to OPENERP from my android project. This what I am doing,

```
    private URI uri;
    uri = URI.create("http://192.168.100.29:8069");
    client = new XMLRPCClient(uri);

    Array[] arr;
    arr = (Array[]) client.call("search", "DevDB", "admin",
                "password", "product.product", "execute");


   HttpResponse response;
   response = client.execute(postMethod); 

   String res = null;
     if (null != response) {
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
            res = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
        }
```

**Update:**

```
 OpenErpConnect op = OpenErpConnect.connect("http://192.168.100.29:8069/", 8069, "DevDB", "admin", "openerp");
```

And in XMLRPClient,

```
    URL loginUrl = new URL("http://192.168.100.29:8069/");
    XMLRPCClient client = new XMLRPCClient(loginUrl);
    Integer id = (Integer)client.call("login", db, user, pass);
    connection = new OpenErpConnect(server, port, db, user, pass, id);
```

But I always get the response as a html file. I don't know where I am going wrong.
Can any body please help me?

**Update:**

First, I'm really sorry to continue from here. But because my original question was regarding to search, I continue here only. Please apologize.

I am able to login with this code now,

```
       OpenErpConnect localOpenErpConnect = new OpenErpConnect(
                paramString1, paramString2, paramInteger, paramString3,
                paramString4, paramString5,
                (Integer) new XMLRPCClient(new URL(paramString1,
                        paramString2, paramInteger.intValue(),
                        "/xmlrpc/common")).call("login", paramString3,
                        paramString4, paramString5));
```

But when I do search request like this,

```
        Long[] ids = conn.search("product.product", new Object[0]);
        System.out.println(ids); 


        Object[] responseIds = (Object[]) client.call("execute",
                    parameters);
```

I'm getting the error that,

```
            Traceback (most recent call last):
                  File "/opt/openerp/v7/server/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 82,      in xmlrpc_return
             result = openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service, method, params)
            File "/opt/openerp/v7/server/openerp/netsvc.py", line 292, in dispatch_rpc
            result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
            File "/opt/openerp/v7/server/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 611, in dispatch
             (db, uid, passwd ) = params[0:3]
         ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Can you help me?

Comment: No one knows the answer?

Comment: Can you include at least part of the response? It may give clues to the problem.

Comment: @DonKirkby, I am able to login now using OpenerpCOnnect class. But having problem with search still

Comment: Please show how you create the `conn` object. It should connect to the other URL that Parthiv suggested.

Answer (score 2):

you are making request to wrong URI. URL should be `http://192.168.100.29:8069/xmlrpc/object` to execute any function over openerp object.

You can also refer to this link. https://doc.openerp.com/6.0/de/developer/6_22_XML-RPC_web_services/#java

Comment: @Parhiv, I am able to login now using OpenERpConnect class. How ever still having problem with search method

Comment: I'm able to connect with this code OpenErpConnect localOpenErpConnect = new OpenErpConnect(
     paramString1, paramString2, paramInteger, paramString3,
     paramString4, paramString5,
     (Integer) new XMLRPCClient(new URL(paramString1,
       paramString2, paramInteger.intValue(),
       "/xmlrpc/common")).call("login", paramString3,
       paramString4, paramString5));. I tried using the url you gave. But it is not working

Comment: Now, my problem is the original search request. Do you have any idea?

Comment: old thread, but xmlrpc/common are used only to login to openerp. To call other method, use xmlrpc/object instead